# Xerces error when deploying Web Service on Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws, xerces

Whenever I try to deploy a JAX-WS web service on Tomcat 8, I get the the following error:

```
 4-Mar-2015 10:35:35.730 SEVERE [http-nio-8085-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1496)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Even with the error, I am able to deploy the web-service 20% of the time, but most of the time it will just fail to deploy.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comments, I'm listing the contents of WEB-INF\lib:

```
03/09/2015  08:53 AM            62,983 activation-1.1.jar
03/10/2015  04:43 PM             4,467 aopalliance-1.0.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM            63,966 avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM            21,007 commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           232,019 commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           284,184 commons-codec-1.10.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM            34,827 commons-csv-1.0.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           160,519 commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           185,140 commons-io-2.4.jar
03/10/2015  04:43 PM           284,220 commons-lang-2.6.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           412,739 commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM            52,915 commons-logging-1.1.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM            96,221 commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM         8,613,667 eclipselink-2.5.1.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           206,853 gson-2.3.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM            31,245 gt-epsg-extension-11.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM         1,960,275 gt-epsg-hsql-11.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           505,719 gt-metadata-11.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           345,672 gt-opengis-11.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM         1,143,704 gt-referencing-11.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM         1,395,415 hsqldb-2.2.8.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           590,533 httpclient-4.3.5.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           282,269 httpcore-4.3.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM            38,605 jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           225,316 jackson-core-2.4.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM         1,075,759 jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM         1,900,631 jai_core-1.1.3.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM             2,497 javax.inject-1.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM           162,126 javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar
03/24/2015  03:59 PM           102,528 jaxb-api-2.2.12-b141001.1542.jar
03/19/2015  03:32 PM           854,901 jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM           144,283 jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.9.1.jar
03/09/2015  08:53 AM            33,428 jaxws-api-2.1.jar
03/19/2015  03:32 PM         1,284,131 jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM            16,458 jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.1.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM            11,497 jgridshift-1.0.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           586,201 joda-time-2.4.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM            54,203 json-smart-1.2.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM            91,347 jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           710,293 jts-1.11.jar
03/19/2015  03:32 PM           121,658 junit-3.8.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           489,884 log4j-1.2.17.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM            72,150 logkit-1.0.1.jar
03/09/2015  09:46 AM           388,864 mail-1.4.jar
03/19/2015  03:32 PM            38,665 mimepull-1.2.jar
03/25/2015  10:33 AM           429,408 mojo-MojoGlobal-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
03/20/2015  11:43 AM            75,239 MojoAlerts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
03/25/2015  10:33 AM           757,460 MojoInterfaces-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
03/25/2015  10:33 AM           571,604 MojoSimulation-1.0.jar
03/24/2015  02:03 PM         3,389,454 ojdbc6-6.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM         2,097,954 PDFRenderer-0.9.0.jar
03/09/2015  08:53 AM            68,177 resolver-20050927.jar
03/09/2015  08:53 AM            18,817 saaj-api-1.3.jar
03/19/2015  03:32 PM           278,293 saaj-impl-1.3.1.jar
03/19/2015  03:32 PM           332,055 sjsxp-1.0.1.jar
03/16/2015  07:53 AM            26,065 slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM             8,867 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.9.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           337,694 spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           612,569 spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           866,273 spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           873,608 spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           383,327 spring-data-commons-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           196,367 spring-expression-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:52 AM           405,717 spring-jdbc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           374,411 spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           366,941 spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
03/16/2015  07:50 AM           242,436 spring-tx-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
03/19/2015  03:32 PM            26,310 stax-api-1.0.jar
03/09/2015  08:53 AM            11,074 stax-ex-1.2.jar
03/19/2015  03:32 PM            57,984 streambuffer-0.7.jar
03/16/2015  07:48 AM           249,354 vecmath-1.3.2.jar
03/26/2015  08:53 AM           895,924 xercesImpl-2.4.0.jar
```

**UPDATE 2**

Changing the xercesImpl version from 2.4.0 to 2.11.0 (most current) seemed to resolve the `ClassCastException` but it generated the following error:

```
    INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
Mar 26, 2015 11:47:43 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1542)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.readers.SAXCatalogReader.readCatalog(SAXCatalogReader.java:238)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.Catalog.parseCatalog(Catalog.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.createEntityResolver(XmlUtil.java:270)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.createEntityResolver(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:402)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:547)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1516)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:371)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From what I could gather, the `Illegal access` seems to still be related to the xerces dependency

Comment: This smells like a classpath conflict with duplicate jars. You may be having some API/implementation mismatches which depending on which order that Java loads the jars might work or not work. I would inspect what jars you deploy with the application, possibly there are some Xalan / Xerces jars that are conflicting with other (older?) jars that are also present on your classpath

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a Maven project. I looked for conflicting jars in the `pom.xml` but couldn't find any.

Comment: Suggestion: list the jars in the target `WEB-INF/lib` here. You may have to use some exclusions in your pom (or mark something as provided). They could be transitive dependencies being pulled in that are in conflict with a system or parent classloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got two Xerces related errors, so I'm posting my approach to solve each one:

The `ClassCastException` error was solved by updating to the latest version of xerces:

```
        <dependency>
             <groupId>xerces</groupId>
             <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
             <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

As mentioned in the comments, make sure you remove any other Xerces related dependencies and leave just the one above.

To solve the `Illegal Access` issue, I found [this post](https://www.java.net/node/704888) with a proposed solution to remove the following files from the `xerces-Impl.jar`

`META-INF/service/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`

`META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory`

I realize changing the dependency is a bit of a hack and it may backfire if the file in the local maven repo is deleted and re-downloaded from Maven Central, but that was the best solution I could find.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I'm using gradle to build my web-app deployed to tomcat.  I determined the version of xerces being used via the "gradle dependencies" command.  Then I indicated in the build.gradle file that xerces would be provided.

providedCompile "xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1"

The problem appears to be resolved.

I know you can do the same thing in maven using the provided scope.

Answer (score -2):

i solved this problem removing the xerces-Impl.jar from lib folder

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case it wasn't that simple. `xerces-Impl.jar` is a needed JAX-WS dependency, and removing it just causes other errors.